# Android Analog Stick for a Game

Tags: java, android

I need some help with my android game. I want to set up an analog stick - 2 circles. 1 moveable. When you hold the smaller one it moves the character on screen.

Now I'am using DrawableImages to change the values but this is not very comfortable:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.upButton:
                gameEngine.moveUp();
                return true;
            case R.id.downButton:
                gameEngine.moveDown();
                return true;
            case R.id.leftButton:
                gameEngine.moveLeft();
                return true;
            case R.id.rightButton:
                gameEngine.moveRight();
                return true;
            case R.id.down_left:
                gameEngine.moveDownLeft();
                return true;
            case R.id.down_right:
                gameEngine.moveDownRight();
                return true;
            case R.id.up_left:
                gameEngine.moveUpLeft();
                return true;
            case R.id.up_right:
                gameEngine.moveUpRight();
                return true;
            case R.id.button_attack:
                paintGame.setAttack();
                gameEngine.attack();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

public void moveUp(){
    charX -= 8;


}
public void moveDown(){
    charX += 8;


}
public void moveRight(){
    charY +=8;


}
public void moveLeft(){
    charY -= 8;


}
public void moveDownLeft(){
    charX += 4;
    charY -= 4;


}
public void moveUpLeft(){
    charX -= 4;
    charY -= 4;


}
public void moveDownRight(){
    charX += 4;
    charY +=4;


}
public void moveUpRight(){
    charX -= 4;
    charY +=4;


}
```

I don't know how i can realize   this. I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because seems a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement your custom Android View and handle touch events by your own + making animations. Or use [this](https://code.google.com/p/mobile-anarchy-widgets/wiki/JoystickView).

Comment: Remember to approve answer if it helps.